# Duplicate data for OneToMany mapping in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

While doing insert in Hibernate for OneToMany mapping. Same data is getting inserted twice.

Employee:

```
@Entity
public class Employee {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int empId;
    private String name;
    private String designation;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "employee", fetch = FetchType.EAGER, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
}
```

Address:

```
@Entity
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private int addressID;
    private String city;
    private String country;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinColumn(name = "empId")
    @JsonIgnore
    private Employee employee;
}
```

When I use POST request to save the data:
Save request for 1st employee:

```
{
  "name": "Test1",
  "designation": "SAL1",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "city": "Delhi",
      "country": "India"
    },
     {
      "city": "Noida",
      "country": "India"
    }
  ]
}
```

Save request for 2nd employee:

```
{
  "name": "Test2",
  "designation": "SAL2",
  "addresses": [
    {
      "city": "Delhi",
      "country": "India"
    },
     {
      "city": "Noida",
      "country": "India"
    }
  ]
}
```

In this case in Address tables contains 4 entries 2 each for Noida:India and Delhi:India.

I wanted to understand what is the best way to have only 1 entry for each address data i.e 1 for Noida:India and 1 for Delhi:India.

Comment: Check to see if your request is being sent twice.

Comment: No,I am sending it twice for 2 different employees but I want if we already have that address in address table its should map to that instead of creating a new row in address table.

Comment: Then you need to create a composite key which contains country and city. Look into composite keys

Answer (score 0):

Create a separate table which stores location entries. Have the key for this table be a composite key of "country" and "city". Then, create a separate address table which has a foreign key column for "user" and the table containing countries and cities.